# Этимология слова «гамбургер»

Tags: этимология, история

Как появилось это слово в русском языке и какова его этимология?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Слово заимствовано из американского английского (hamburger), где оно со временем стало обозначать бутерброд на основе булочки с рубленым бифштексом; слово может также трактоваться как "гамбургский", "по-гамбургски" и совпадает со словом Hamburger (житель Гамбурга).

*(The Diner's Dictionary: Word Origins of Food and Drink, John Ayto, 1990)*

Первоначально слово hamburger использовалось для обозначения сорта немецкой колбасы. По одному из предположений, мясное изделие из рубленого мяса, на которое много позже перешло наименование *hamburger meat* (мясо по-гамбургски), задолго до этого возникло в Балтийском регионе, даже ссылаются на русский говяжий "биток". Затем через немецких эмигрантов и моряков (которые, предположительно, брали такую еду в дорогу) блюдо со временем попало в американские ресторанные сети.

https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=NoicAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA166&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&ots=NbcAkypmZl&sig=ACfU3U0tqduDxr2jzRcXrnT7R6Z38YcJEg&w=1280

Хронология фиксации наименования в американском английском:

1880-xx (упоминания о мясном изделии hamburger steak - гамбургский бифштекс)

1884 Упоминание "гамбургского бифштекса" (hamburg steak) в газете Boston Evening Journal

1885 На ярмарке в Сеймуре (штат Висконсин) Чарли Нагрин с успехом предлагал это мясное блюдо под наименованием American Hamburger

1902 использование слова как сокращения от hamburger sandwich (бутерброд по-гамбургски)

1904 - Всемирная ярмарка в Сент-Луисе, где под наименованием hamburger хорошо расходилось блюдо из рубленого мяса

1909 первое упоминание о бутерброде, состоящем из булочки с мясом по-гамбургски ("a sandwich consisting of a bun and a patty of grilled hamburger meat")

1921 Появление сети ресторанов The White Castle Hamburger (Уичита, штат Канзас)

1939 появилось сокращение burger

1940 появление сети ресторанов "Макдональдс"

Online Etymology Dictionary:

https://www.etymonline.com/word/hamburger

http://www.todayifoundout.com/index.php/2010/09/why-a-hamburger-is-called-a-hamburger/

По данным упомянутого *The Diner's Dictionary*, в конце 50-x, когда происхождение слова было подзабыто, по недоразумению появилась его разделённая трактовка как ham-burger (ham - ветчина). Сначала попытались "уточнить" слово, привязав его к говядине (beefburger), затем началось массовое словообразование добавлением ингредиентов к основе -burger (чизбургеры и др.). В русском все варианты слова стали активно использоваться с открытием сети "Макдональдс" (с 1990 года).

Answer (score 0):

Слово «гамбургер» 'разновидность сэндвича' появилось примерно в середине 1970-х годов (в речи эмигрантов), а широкое распространение получило начиная с конца 1990 года, когда в Москве открылся первый американский ресторан быстрого питания «Макдоналдс».

Это заимствование из английского языка, где *hamburger* 'разновидность сэндвича' известно c 1900 года. Название дано по городу Гамбургу (англ. *Hamburg*), откуда шел основной поток эмигрантов из Европы.

*(По Русскому этимологическому словарю РАН А. Е. Аникина.)*

Вероятно, подходящей аналогией может служить название кулинарных блюд по городам и в русском языке, например: [салат «Париж»](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B6&oq=%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B6&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2673j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).